# Blazor Parameter Object or child API call or Virualization?

Tags: c#, rest, parameter-passing, virtualization, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a project that includes a list of Help Articles.

Clicking on an Article in the list opens the Article.

OnInitializedAsync() calls to the API for the **Article**.include(**Comments**).theninclude(**Replies**).

I have a **CommentList** component that builds the comment list using instances of **Comment** component

Each **Comment** has a **ReplyList** component that builds a reply list using instances of **Reply** component

The page is built:

- **Article** API Call including Comments then Replies
- **CommentList** `[Parameter] public <ArticleDto> Article`
- **Comment** instances `[Parameter] public <CommentDto> Comment`
- **ReplyList** `[Parameter] public <ReplyDto> Reply`
- **Reply** instances `[Parameter] public <ReplyDto> Reply`

The page is slow to render with a lot of `foreach` and `if` checks so I'm left wondering if my approach is a bit immature?

If you've faced this dilemma, I'd love to hear what your approach was.

I'm considering having each list component make its own API call but I was hoping to avoid multiple calls to build a single page. Virtualization seems like a good candidate perhaps?

Comment: could be slow because of latency, db calls, try to replace your db data with fake static data you create in a for loop, obviously showing 1k records at once will also be slow, fot that you can use paging

Comment: Thanks, @buga it's all running local with avg 38ms latency. Adjusting the hierarchy of the components and refining conditional loops along with fewer EventCallbacks has resolved the issue.